# Found this in a pot today. Anyone know what it is?

Tags: containers, ficus

Found this in a pot today. Anyone know what it is? [image]

Comment: I can;t quite tell if those globules have stalks on them - pull  one out to see if its a toadstool of some sort. there is a slime mould present which would indicate the soil in the pot is wet.

Comment: Almost looks like Osmocote, but would need to see something to indicate the scale of the photo to be sure. Is this a pot that came from a plant nursery?

Answer (score 1):

These are a commercial slow release fertilizer called [Osmocote](https://www.scottsbrands.com/en-us/products/osmocote/osmocote-smart-release-plant-food-plus-outdoor-indoor) described as

> Each granule is coated with a unique resin that controls nutritional
> release so that plants get what they need, when they need it.

It is widely used in the greenhouse and nursery industry. If you pick up one of the little beads most of them should be empty and you can easily crush it.

Osmocote fertilizer and the resin shell is not considered harmful and can be left in the pot.

Answer (score 0):

That is just slow release fertilizer. Most potting soil has it.